# F# How do I make a board for a game in f#?

Tags: f#

I want to make a small simulation, but I can't figure out how to make the board for the simulation. 
I want to make a simulation where there are two kind of animals predators and prey. 
The simulation should be given an input n, which determines the size of the board. So that it is n x n squares big. 
I have tried to use a 2D array, but I don't completely understand it and when I try to print my board it doesn't show up.

I have an .fs file with this code

```
module preditorprey

type board(n:int) =
    let _rows = n
    let _columns = n
    let _board = Array2D.create _rows _columns (None)
```

I then have an .fsx file with this

```
open preditorprey 

let boards = preditorprey.board(8)

printfn "%A" boards
```

However when I run the code it just returns

```
preditorprey+board
```

Why does it do this and how do I make it print out a board with n*n squares???

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it do this

You created a class `board` and defined some [private fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/let-bindings-in-classes). You are surprised that `printfn "%A"` does not return the data inside the `Board` type. Since the fields inside the Board type are private, no function can access them, so this would not be possible.

`printfn "%A"` has special code to print a lot of F# structures in a reasonably intelligent way. For classes it will use the `ToString()` method which defaults to printing out the class name.

> how do I make it print out a board with n*n squares???

For something quick and dirty (i.e. without specifying what you mean by printing out a board but just relying on a moderate approach and a lot of defaults), you could do one of the following. Note the conventional naming: Pascal case for types, caml case for fields. Also note that you are missing a type annotation on None.

```ml
type NeedsToBeSpecified = class end

let boardA(n:int) = Array2D.create n n (None: NeedsToBeSpecified option)
let a = boardA(8)
printfn "%A" a

type BoardB(n:int) =
    let board = Array2D.create n n (None: NeedsToBeSpecified option)
    member t.Board = board
let b = BoardB(8)
printfn "%A" b.Board

type BoardC(n:int) =
    let board = Array2D.create n n (None: NeedsToBeSpecified option)
    override _.ToString() = sprintf "%A" board
let z = BoardC(8)
printfn "%A" z
```